# How to dynamic create function variants from an enum?

Tags: python, function, enums

Suppose there is a class defining a few standard functions where one of them is a function to initiate a command. Here 2 examples:

```
Ser.Cmd(CmdEnum.MoveAbsolute,10,20,'Ack')
Ser.Cmd(CmdEnum.MoveRelative,5,0,'Ack')
```

where CmdEnum.MoveAbsolute and CmdEnum.MoveRelative are enumerate values for the specific command to execute.

In this class there are also other "generic" functions such as Ser.enable or Ser.getstatus.

The usability of the class would be more clean if the syntax of the command could change into:

```
Ser.MoveAbsolute(10,20,'Ack')
```

Is it possible to create functions in this style by passing an enum type during object creation?

Can someone give an example?

The idea is to not have the part ".MoveAbsolute" hard coded in the class, but being specified based on the enumerate value that is passed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `functools.partial` function for this.

```
import functools

class MySer(Ser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.MoveAbsolute = functools.partial(self.Cmd, CmdEnum.MoveAbsolute)
        self.MoveRelative = functools.partial(self.Cmd, CmdEnum.MoveRelative)
```

You can now call your functions like this:

```
ser = MySer()
ser.MoveAbsolute(10, 20, 'Ack')
```

Comment: In this example the functions are hard-coded. Would it be an option to use "eval" to even not have the "self.MoveAbsolute" but instead specify "self."+string = ....?

Comment: You could use `setattr` here. `setattr(MySer, s, functools.partial(self.Cmd, getattr(CmdEnum, s)))` should do the job. But I wouldn' t recommend that because it makes the code more difficult to read. This way you might easily loose track of the implemented functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need enums as you can indicate the functions directly:

So instead of:

```
Ser.Cmd(CmdEnum.MoveAbsolute,10,20,'Ack')
Ser.Cmd(CmdEnum.MoveRelative,5,0,'Ack')
```

which might call:

```
Ser.MoveAbsolute(10,20,'Ack')
```

you can write:

```
Ser.Cmd(Ser.MoveAbsolute,10,20,'Ack')
```

but the implementation of `Cmd` would be:

```
def Cmd(self, func, *args):
    func(*args)
```